# How do I get all the items from Java list from specified position ignoring all its previous without using IndexOf/sublist() method?

Tags: java

KeyValueAccess kva = KeyValueAccessFactoryForTestConfig.getConnection();
        List> keySets = kva.getDistinctPartitionKeys(SavepointDto.class, Integer.valueOf(50));

```
    List<Pair<String, String>> pairs =
            keySets.stream()
                    .sorted((k1, k2) -> SavepointUtils.compareMinitues(k1.get(1), k2.get(1)))
                    .sorted((k1, k2) -> k1.get(0).compareTo(k2.get(1)))
                    .map(keySet -> Pair.of(keySet.get(0), keySet.get(1)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("\n");

    int index = pairs.indexOf("2016:6:29:13:27");

    for (int i = index; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(pairs.get(i));
    }

}
```

I'm Having a `List<Pair<String, String>>` when I'm trying to get index of any specific element from list I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException` (See above code) in my case the 1st element is date (ex: `2016:6:29:13:27`) of `String` type.
 so can't use `indexOf` or `substring()` method.

Is there any other way to get all the elements from list from specific position by ignoring previous elements???

Comment: Use list.sublist(int fromIndex, int toIndex)

Comment: Hint: especially for the collections library ... take some time to digest the javadoc for it. You will be surprised to find how many useful operations are there. And you know: all of that is properly documented!

Comment: I've a List<Pair<String, String>> when i'm trying to get index of particular pair i'm getting ArrayarrayIndexoutofboundsException & without knowing index sublist method is useless.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, you want to skip some elements in the list but you don't write which ones. From the question above it is possible using index or old style loop, if you have equals method in your Pair.

Comment: My hypothesis is that you misunderstood what `Iterables.concat` does, it does not "flatten" your "Pair" of strings. The `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException` is pretty much expected, because `indexOf(String)` will never be > 0 on a list of pairs. And please don't *unformat* your question

Comment: Ohh U'r right i think...how to resolve this problem then?? i got fed in resolving this this issue..plz help!

Comment: @krzyk : I Simply want all the elements in list after specific position but in my case i'm not getting index of element(pls see screenshot) so can't us skip(),indexOf or sublist() method.

Comment: After a specific position, position means index, so how do you want to achieve that without index/position?

Comment: Your `indexOf` is not working because you are trying to find index of a `String` inside a `List` of `Pair` (BTW. From what library do you have this `Pair`)?

Comment: Also please, don't provide a screenshot with code, instead paste the code into the question as a text.

Comment: @krzyk : See I've a service method which takes date as an argument of String type, when this service will execute it should show all the data (which is a pair of String & date itself )after that date by ignoring all previous data before that date. Pair API from org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<L,R>

Comment: I've also tried with list.stream().filter(s-> s.contains("2016:6:29:13:27")) but its only giving particular that record, i think their should be some way by to resolve this problem using stream filter() but i dint got success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream for that ([`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) first 2 elements):

```
Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e").stream()
    .skip(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e");
    list.subList(2, list.size());
```

Comment: Already tried with Java 8 stream skip() method but in my case i'm not getting expected result..sorting issue i'm facing.. I've a List<Pair<String, String>> when i'm trying to get index of particular pair i'm getting ArrayarrayIndexoutofboundsException

Comment: @VinayThakre How does a skip result in an error? Please update your question with a `Pair` example, or ask another more specific question. Your current one works with the code in the above answer.

Comment: skip method not throwing any error..its executing but i'm getting expected result.